# getting keys form the json file using node.js

Tags: json, node.js

I'm trying to get the keys from this json file but dont know how to get it

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452', function(error, response, data) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        //console.log(data) 
    }
})
```

Comment: You can get the keys by using `Object.keys(data);` Would be better if you can post the response json to get correct answers. :)

Comment: but that is just giving me numbers

Comment: that is why I asked your to post your received response :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Object.keys() Method:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(Object.keys(arr)); // console: ['0', '1', '2']

// array like object
var obj = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // console: ['0', '1', '2']

// array like object with random key ordering
var an_obj = { 100: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: 'c' };
console.log(Object.keys(an_obj)); // console: ['2', '7', '100']
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)